# How to use graphics card only for deep learning and not display?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

I have a 2 GB graphics card which I am using for training deep learning models on large data. But it's hampering my display (showing weird color pixels on the screen) while running the program. Is it possible to use graphics card only for computation and not for display? I am sure it must be possible to disconnect graphics card from display but I want it to be available for computation. How could I achieve it?

Comment: Mate, your question makes no sense. On one hand you are saying the graphics are stuffed when you use it for computation, on the other you say you don't want to use it for display. The short answer is turn off your monitor and you are done. A perhaps more helpful answer is get another graphics adapter or use the one that's on your motherboard for display.

Answer (score 3):

NVIDIA has [a suggestion for this question](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).

Their recommendation is to use two GPUs: one for X, and one for computation.  They also suggest disabling X, limiting the CUDA kernel to short execution times, and turning off interactive mode in the NVIDIA driver.

You don't say that you're using an NVIDIA graphics card, but some of these suggestions may work for any graphics card.

If your motherboard has onboard graphics in addition to a discrete graphics card, you may be able to configure the BIOS to use the onboard graphics for your display.